# Running ubuntu -headless- on early PiB

Tags: ubuntu

I am tinkering around with an old PiB
It's currently running - no GUI - under Buster
Can I get it running headless with ubuntu?
(I am using ubuntu headless on a couple or more recent Pi's and would prefer to keep to the one OS)
If so, where can I get the .img from?
I have looked on ubuntu.com - nothing.

Comment: doesn't look like there is an Ubuntu compatible with the original Pi's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original Pi (pre Pi2) are ARM6. There never was an ARM6 version of Ubuntu (although there was an unofficial Ubuntu MATE produced by a user).

All current Ubuntu require ARM7 (preferably ARM8) and need more memory.